# Appending entry to array is causing all previous entries to be changed to latest entry

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to take a 3 digit number then generate children in the following order:
a. 1 is subtracted from the first digit
b. 1 is added to the first digit
c. 1 is subtracted from the second digit
d. 1 is added to the second digit
e. 1 is subtracted from the third digit
f.1 is added to the third digit

Don't subtract if 0 and don't add if 9.

Here's the code I'm using to do it where p is an array of 3 digits

```
def generate_children(p):
    children = []
    i=0
    for x in p:
        if x != 0:
            child1 = p
            child1[i] = child1[i]-1
            children.append(child1)
            print(children)
        if x != 9:
            child2 = p
            child2[i] = child2[i] + 1
            children.append(child2)
            print(children)
        i+=1
    return children
```

If I give this a parent of 345 it should return [245,445,335,355,344,346] at the end. However when I run it with the print statements it gives me below. Why does every entry in the array become the same after being appended?

[[2, 4, 5]]

[[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

[[3, 3, 5], [3, 3, 5], [3, 3, 5]]

[[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

[[3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4]]

[[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

Comment: What is the data type of `p`? It would be better if you would provide the code to call this function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: @Manuel I don't think that will help the OP, as in that case it's a subtlety of how the `*` operation works for lists, whereas in this case it has to do with confusion about variables/references vs values.

Comment: @augurar I see it as the same issue, just created differently, and I think understanding the issue as explained for that other case (i.e., that all sublists are the same list object) will also make them understand this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use list.copy()

```py
def generate_children(p):
    children = []
    i = 0
    for x in p:
        if x != 0:
            child1 = p.copy()
            child1[i] = child1[i] - 1
            children.append(child1)
            print(children)
        if x != 9:
            child2 = p.copy()
            child2[i] = child2[i] + 1
            children.append(child2)
            print(children)
        i += 1
    return children
```

In python, if you bind a name to a list, it doesn't copy the list, it point to the same memory slot.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
# a -----> [1, 2, 3]

b = a
# a -----> [1, 2, 3]
#          ^
#          |
# b --------

a[1] = 4
# a -----> [1, 4, 3]
#          ^
#          |
# b --------
print(b)  # [1, 4, 3]
```

if you use `list.copy()`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
# a -----> [1, 2, 3]

b = a.copy()
# a -----> [1, 2, 3]
# b -----> [1, 2, 3]

a[1] = 4
# a -----> [1, 4, 3]
# b -----> [1, 2, 3]

print(b)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

#### You code:

You can visualize the behavior of your code here: [generate_children behavior](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%0Adef%20generate_children%28p%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20children%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20i%20%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20for%20x%20in%20p%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20!%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child1%20%3D%20p%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child1%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20child1%5Bi%5D%20-%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children.append%28child1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28children%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20!%3D%209%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child2%20%3D%20p%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child2%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20child2%5Bi%5D%20%2B%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children.append%28child2%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28children%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20i%20%2B%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20return%20children%0A%0A%0Aprint%28generate_children%28%5B3,%204,%206%5D%29%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[image: original code]

#### Fixed code:

You can visualize the behavior of the fixed code here: [fixed_generate_children behavior](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20fixed_generate_children%28p%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20children%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20i%20%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20for%20x%20in%20p%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20!%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child1%20%3D%20p.copy%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child1%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20child1%5Bi%5D%20-%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children.append%28child1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28children%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20!%3D%209%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child2%20%3D%20p.copy%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child2%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20child2%5Bi%5D%20%2B%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children.append%28child2%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28children%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20i%20%2B%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20return%20children%0A%20%20%20%20%0Afixed_generate_children%28%5B3,%204,%206%5D%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[image: fixed code]